# Android BLE Scan unstable 6.0.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Android 6.0.1 and I am facing BLE Scan issue. The problem is sometimes the scan results return no device and sometimes it returns device. It means I have a remote device by name 'A'. 'A' is discovered and shown in my app once and again after few seconds, 'A' disappears in my discovered window and again re-appears after few seconds. This is the problem which I am facing in Samsung S5. But the same app running in Samsung S6 and S7 works fine with scanning.

I have given necessary permission for Location Services too and my GPS is ON. What could be the problem stil?

Comment: BLE devices advertise at a certain interval. It is normal that your app does not always see the advertisement packet

Comment: Tim is right. I've found that the device will be discovered from time to time. If you don't leave the scan to scan for long enough sometimes the device wont be picked up at all. In most cases an advertisement packet will appear at least once in 50 seconds, I put the timeout to 60 seconds to ensure the advertisement packet is found.

Comment: @TimCastelijns thank you but the same app or same code works fine for other 6.0.1 devices. How is this possible?

Comment: Tim and Mark are better suited to help you here, and I'm talking off the top of my head, but check if the radios are the same. Different radios implement detection slightly differently, and that slight difference is enough to make you wish Bluetooth never existed and that we wired everything with copper wires.

Comment: Bluetooth scanning *can* act differently on every device and/or android version. It is heavily reliant on the specific bluetooth chip on the device, and the drivers the manufacturer wrote for it. You can never expect bluetooth to function the same across devices/versions

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 - Could you please tell me where I could add this delay of 60s?

Comment: @AlexPierro I'm still to this date having issues with Samsung devices and BLE, if you can get consistent results with them, please ping me. For whatever reason whenever I was testing BLE on the S6 I had more success but no where near to the same degree as my Nexus 6P which is successful with BLE connections basically every time.

Comment: @AlexPierro I've setup a `CountDownTimer` which calls `mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback)` or `mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback)` when `onFinish()` for the `CountDownTimer`, depending on which Android version you're using.

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 Thank you for the idea. Yes sure once it is stable in S6 I will let u know :)